# wp_nav_menu only prints menu if I don't include the location (which was registered)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was able to register a new menu location (it shows in the admin `Appearance->Menus` section. But when I call wp_nav_menu with that location, it prints nothing. If I set `location =>''` then it prints it!

**functions.php**

```
//This works
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
function register_my_menus()
{
    register_nav_menus( array( 'my_special_slug' => __( 'My Menu' )));
}
```

**header.php**

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'items_wrap'=> '%3$s', 
        'walker' => new MyWalker(), 
        'container'=>false, 
        'menu_class' => '', 
        'theme_location'=>'my_special_slug', //This does NOT work
        'fallback_cb'=>false 
    )
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe also add in `'menu' => 'My Menu'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears (please correct me if this is incorrect) that without the user going into the admin interface and turning the menu on, it cannot be found. They need to go to `Appearance->Menus->Locations" and select the menu to show for that location.

I have been unable to find a programmatic way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

`register_nav_menu` takes a [comma separated array.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu)

```
function register_my_menus()
{
    register_nav_menu(array( 'my_special_slug', 'My Menu');
}
```

Comment: I copied weekday is in the default twentyfourteen theme. and the WordPress documentation also shows it the way I have it. you linked to a different function: the singular one.

Comment: Maybe the problem is you're only creating one menu with a function that creates multiple?

Comment: It appears (please correct me if this is incorrect) that without the user going into the admin interface and turning the menu on, it cannot be found. They need to go to `Appearance->Menus->Locations" and select the menu to show for that location.

I have been unable to find a programmatic way of doing this.

Comment: If you call the menu in your code you shouldn't have to select it for a location. Or that was my impression. However [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) reads like you maybe do have to go to `Appearance->Menus` to do it.

Comment: try it. unless they added menu items to it, it will be blank

Comment: is this line for sure in your theme's functions.php `add_theme_support( 'menus' );`

Comment: yes, I even tested it by just adding my code to the twentyfourteen theme.